# Looping setTimeout in an IIFE as opposed to not using var as the iteration variable

Tags: javascript, iife

I was going through an example explaining the use of `var` in a loop where there is a `setTimeout`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);
}
```

logs out

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

The explanation is that the loop executes completely and then the `setTimeout`.

In the following example, `setTimeout` block is wrapped in an immediately-invoked function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

which shows

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Is this because of both:

1. An IIFE executing immediately means that even if it contained a `setTimeout`, the `setTimeout` would be executed immediately. I.e. An IIFE trumps any asynchronous code inside it and executes it immediately?
2. The function scoping of the IIFE shadows `i` but creates a separate variable that tracks the value of the outer `i` at each iteration

---

**EDIT (An additional question that I didn't articulate well in the original post):**

Why does asynchronous code (`setTimeout`) execute after the loop is completed whereas in the second example it executes immediately at each iteration?

Thanks

Comment: It is answer 2.

Comment: ``i`` of outer function is pulled by setTimeout and cannot be released

Comment: Prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 for me in both cases

Comment: @super you must be using `let` or otherwise not executing *this* code. I rule out the possibility for your JavaScript engine to be non-compliant, so its not possible to get this result. [Example](https://jsbin.com/hejidu/edit?js,console)

Comment: It's fully compliant, I just ran it inside my time machine.

Comment: "*Why does asynchronous code (setTimeout) execute after the loop is completed whereas in the second example it executes immediately at each iteration?*" that's not what happens. In the second example `setTimeout` still schedules something to be executed *later* and that will *always* be after the loop finishes. [You can verify here](https://jsbin.com/liwenef/edit?js,console). With an IIFE the `i` variable is shadowed. It really doesn't need to be named `i` - in effect it's just a *different* variable. [See here](https://jsbin.com/mutuvit/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ I see. So is the sequence of execution in your example something like: for loop fully executes --> `console.log("loop finished")` --> 1st `setTimeout` execution with scoped variable of first iteration of the for loop (i.e. 0) --> 2nd `setTimeout` execution with scoped variable of second iteration of the for loop (i.e. 1) ... last `setTimeout` execution with scoped variable of last iteration of the for loop (i.e. 9)?

Comment: Yes. With the IIFE, you get a *new* set of variables. Without it and when using a `var` what happens is that every function executes and subsequently uses *the same* `i` as every other. So with `setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);` the `100 * i` is evaluated immediately during the loop. For example, for `i = 3` you'd get `300` guaranteed. However, when the scheduled function executes, it will read the value of `i` *after* the loop finished, which would be `10`. With an IIFE, you simply get a copy of that value `3` that happens to have the same name but is not the same variable